# Get video url given video link

Tags: python, video, youtube-api

The problem is how to get video url if I have video link in Python?
Could you give me any hint of tool of how to perform it?

For example, I have `str = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"`, but I need something like that: `url = http://r3---sn-hp2u-n8ve.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?pcm2cms=yes&ip=...`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't. I was trying to do the same some time ago and discovered that the videos in youtube are divided into 4 to 5 categories according to the security level.

(Naming them naively)

**1st Type:** You can easily find this video by my following link [How to get flv url from youtube videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109139/how-to-get-flv-url-from-youtube-videos/27119636#27119636)

**2nd type:** You can get the video from 1st type manner but the 's' field is separated from it and you need to parse it separately. But it is straightforward and doable.

**3rd type:** you don't have a direct method to obtain the 's' field but it is doable.

**4th type:** This is the mother of all. The youtube server sends an algorithm  and and encoded url as an input to the youtube player. 
    This algorithm is then applied by the player itself and encoded url is decoded (yes it is like this please don't ask for proofs)...

PS: This is by personal experience and I haven't done much theoretical research.